# Dependency injection @EJB don`t work in @WebService

Tags: web-services, jboss, ejb

I am trying to inject DAO object in WebService

```
@Stateless
public class MyDAOImpl implements MyDAO {...}

@Local
public interface MyDAO {...}
```

and in web service i want inject this DAO:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(endpointInterface = "...")
public class PropertyDetailsWebServiceImpl implements PropertyDetailsWebService {
...
@EJB
MyDAO myDAO; // null pointer
}
```

When I try JNDI - this works:

```
    @Stateless
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "...")
    public class PropertyDetailsWebServiceImpl implements PropertyDetailsWebService {
    ...

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        loggerInstance = (MyDAO ) ic.lookup("java:global/ben/MyDAO Impl!pl.MyDAO");  //this works
    }
```

Why @EJB injection don`t work?

Comment: What version of JBoss/WildFly?

Comment: JBoss EAP 6.4 . . .

Comment: Is this code all in one WAR or is it an EAR deployment? I copied and pasted your code into a maven WAR project (with dummy methods) and the  EJB is injected just fine. I suspect you have some EE7 jars in your deployment that should not be there

Comment: This code is in JAR module "webservices" and this module is in WAR, WAR is in EAR ;)

Comment: Working example at [webservice-41116644](https://github.com/sfcoy/webservice-41116644)

Comment: Thanks @Steve C This works :D

Answer (score 0):

I change maven dependency module webservice from jar to ejb and this works :D

change from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pl.xxx.webservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pl.xxx.webservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>ejb</type> // this 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I would not expect this to make any difference unless the ejb-jar was in the EAR rather than the WAR